# java on osx - xmx ignored?

Tags: java, macos, ubuntu, memory

i've got two computers running on Mac OS X El Capitan and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. On both is Java SDK 1.8.0_101 installed.

When I try to start an game server on Ubuntu with more memory than available, I get the following output:

```
$ java -Xms200G -Xmx200G -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f9b6e580000, 71582613504, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 71582613504 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
#
```

On Mac OS I don't get this error:

```
$ java -Xms200G -Xmx200G -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui
Loading libraries, please wait...
```

Both computers have 8GB of memory. I also tried with an other Apple computer - same problem.

Is that a bug of java mac version?

(Is there a way to force limit the memory usage e.g. to 1GB? -Xmx1G won't work and I wasn't able to find another reason. Not here neither on google)

Thank you!

Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: linux has a 'fixed' swap concept - the amount of memory you have is based on physical RAM + swapfiles. OSX will just keep adding swapfiles if needed (until you run out of disk space). As a result, if you ask linux for more memory than it has, then it will fail, while OSX will say ok, until you actually start using the space; then it can run out of resources. Specifying a maximum size will enforce that limit in the jvm.

Comment: @Petesh that seems fine as answer.

Comment: OS X does not only allocate swap files on disk but also compresses memory. This makes it impossible to determine, how much memory will actually be occupied in compressed state, as some data can be compressed stronger than other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a difference in how the operating systems work. Linux has a concept of a 'fixed' swap - this is based on physical RAM + the various swapfiles/swap partitions added to the system. This is considered the maximum limit of memory that can be committed.

OSX doesn't consider swap as fixed. It will continue to add swapfiles as more and more memory is committed on the operating system (you can see the files being added in `/var/vm`).

As a result, you can ask OSX for significantly more memory than is available and it will effectively reply with 'ok', while under linux it will go 'no'.

The upper-bound limit is still enforced by java - once the heap goes above the size specified it will return a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exception, so if you're specifying a `-Xmx1G` then it should be enforced by the JRE.

You can see the difference with a simple test program:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class memtest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Vector<byte[]> v = new Vector<byte[]>();
        while (true) {
            v.add(new byte[128 * 1024]);
            System.out.println(v.size());
        }

    }
};
```

If this program is run with `-Xmx100M` it dies with a `Java heap space` message after ~730 iterations, when run with `-Xmx1G` it dies with a `Java heap space` message after ~7300 iterations, showing that the limit is being enforced by the java virtual machine.

Comment: You *can* configure linux to permit overcommit, and get a similar behaviour to osx: `sudo sysctl -w vm.overcommit_memory = 1` on linux would allow you to run with `-Xmx200G`; but it's not what you want to have happen.

Comment: Do you know a way to limit memory? I could not find a solution. I typed in Xmx128M but it actually used more than 230MB memory. Prefer it crashes than using more than 128MB. My project is an game server control panel with multiple users. Every user get some quota e.g. 2G

Comment: @user2850375 Xmx limits the size of the java heap, not the process actually running the VM. Notably the binaries and memory allocated outside the heap is not restricted by Xmx.

Comment: If you want to limit the actual memory allocated to the process, you should be able to use `ulimit` to set this limit - it's a shell built-in, `ulimit -m 524288` before invoking the jvm should limit it to 512MB for everything, causing it to crash out of memory once it hits that limit. There's an [example for the limit of the number of files](http://superuser.com/questions/433924/daemontools-and-ulimit), but the principle is the same for memory - wrap the execution of java in a shell script.